# Recommended CLI-only programming environment?

Tags: linux, command-line, distribution-choice, bsd, distributions

I wish to learn and program within a Unix-like OS without a GUI. I'm aware every distribution has a text-only version, but which one is more supportive of this use?

Ideally this would involve conveniences like 'tiling window managers' and 'terminal multiplexers', though that may stray into GUI territory.

I will be using this as learning environment for writing and compiling C code and bourne shell scripts in a terminal editor.

What resources do you recommend for my usecase?

Comment: old school putty and bash is realistically all you really need. Get familiar with the different text editors like vim. If you have a windows computer, boot some linux instances using HyperV. Since you want to develop in C, look up how to install the gcc compiler for your desired distribution of linux.

Comment: My typical setup is one window for a text editor (emacs, but use any editor you like) and one window to type `make` and run the C program. That assumes I have X on my local machine; in a pinch, using `screen` or `tmux` to run both in a single terminal also works. The distro doesn't matter; that works on all distros (and even non-linux ones).

Comment: This question is very subjective: maybe you could focus things a little more? Sure, all distributions contain a command-line interface (even Windows has one...), but what are you trying to find out?